# If I want to limit upvoting to either 1 upvote/downvote, do I have to create a third table in which to store user-image-vote relation?

Tags: php, mysql

So I have added the ability to upvote or downvote uploaded images, however, I would like for each registered user to be able to vote only once.

Currently, I can click upvote 10 times and raise the upvotes to 10, then I can downvote 5 times and get a final rating of 5. I assume I'm gonna need a table that contains an id, the id of the user, the id of the image he has voted on and his vote (upvote or downvote). I'd also want to make it so that the user can change his vote ( from upvote to downvote if he wants to ).

Any good tips or better solutions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: user*, image*, vote - simple, right.

Comment: `I assume I'm gonna need a table that contains an id, the id of the user, the id of the image he has voted on and his vote ` ... that sounds correct to me.  You of course can and should control rogue voting behavior first at the UI, and second at the server.  A wild number of upvotes could almost be like a DOS attack.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how would I control rogue voting behavior first at the UI? Not entirely sure what does that mean.

Comment: You don't need an 'id' - only the ids of the image and user.

Comment: but what's gonna be the primary key of my table then?

Comment: on the front end you can disable the voting buttons after they have been clicked so that the user cannot click them multiple times. When you load the page check if the user/image/vote combination exist and enable only the opposite button (down if vote was up or the opposite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably need a join table called `UserPostVotes` with both primary keys and a third field to indicate how they voted.

Comment: I wonder if I should include a hasVoted column in the table that stores either a 0 or a 1 depending on whether they have previously voted or not?

Comment: I don't see how that would work.  You just want to `select count(1) from UserPostVotes where userId = ? and postId = ?` then `if $results['count'] throw new AlreadyVotedException();`

Comment: Ah yes, that's definitely a wiser approach.

Comment: Probably, you'll also want to join that table when you're loading the page so that you can indicate what the user has already selected and allow him or her to change his or her vote.

Answer (score 0):

For a very basic version that would do the trick :
[image]

Comment: Hmm.  I think you need a field to indicate the disposition of the vote.  Probably a `vote_flag` or `disposition`.

Comment: Yeah maybe but I said that is very simple illustration, the purpose was just to show the relation ship between the tables. The user table will probably contains more than just a name too.

Comment: Sure, but the vote is germane to this context.  I didn't mean to make you defensive.  Certainly more germane than note and name, and its placement is also important.

Comment: Yeap, sry i did not understood what you said. Your right i forgot the placement of the vote. I corrected it.